# Initialization after deletion of constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

My question is this: after deleting a constructor is there any way to initialize a class? For example

```
class A{
    public:
        A() = delete;
        int a = 42;
        int fun(){
            a += 1; 
            return a;
        }
};
```

Now it should not be possible to use this class. For example you cannot:

```
A* instance = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
instance->fun(); //segfault
```

and

```
A instance; //compile error undefined function
```

Assuming for some strange reason you actually wanted to use the class with the constructor deleted is there a way that you could do it? That is without doing something like overriding the constructor.

I know this is a strange question, but I am interested in knowing if someone has a (perhaps obscure) way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Your first example (and I assume you meant `instance->fun();` rather than `a->fun();`) should not actually crash. `a` will be uninitialized but there's no reason for it to crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class is an *aggregate* you can create one using aggregate initialization, which does not call a constructor of `A`. For example:

```
A a = { 1 };
```

In C++11 your class was not an aggregate because of the presence of the `= 42`. So in C++11 your class is unusable.

But in C++14 this was changed, and `= 42` does not prevent the class being an aggregate, so it is usable again.

Comment: It's noteworthy that with C++14, `A a = { };` will use the `= 42` for initialisation of `a`....

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is allowed is that calling `malloc` is not equivalent to calling `new`. `malloc` merely allocates memory and returns where it begins; `new` allocates and constructs an object. Just directly creating an `A`, as in `A instance;`, runs the constructor as well - so it expects it to be there.

As such, it is not an error as you never actually **construct** any `A` object. You allocate uninitialized memory, cast the pointer to `A*`, and then call it. This is valid because the language and the compiler don't care (or likely know) where you got that memory. All it knows is that at runtime, `instance` contains valid allocated memory; if that were not the case, it *might* segfault (it also might not, but would still probably be bad).

What happens when you actually run this is that `fun()` will access uninitialized memory as if it were an `A`; as such, `int a` will be something, but *probably* not 42.

It's not required that a pointer be to a constructable class. For example, you can cast an actual class pointer to one of its non-constructable interface classes and still access it. Effectively, the same methodology that allows that allows this.